# Simple Example SwingUtilities

Tags: java, swing

I have a probably annoying request. Could someone demonstrate how to use one of these static Java swing utility methods? I am looking for a simple, extremely simple, example.

```
public static void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics, java.awt.Component, java.
    awt.Container, int, int, int, int);

  public static void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics, java.awt.Component, java.
awt.Container, java.awt.Rectangle);
```

These static Java swing methods are found in the `javax.swing.SwingUtilities` package.

Thank-you for reading this and any help given.

Comment: Maybe someone could just write a simple program, score some points, increase their self-esteem, instead of rant and toot about the internals of the Java programming language. I do not think this post is asking for much.

Comment: The method is clearly explained in the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html It is used to paint a component on a container without adding the component to the visible containment hierarchy. An example of this might be drawing some text stored in a JLabel on a container, without adding the JLabel to the container. Like @AndrewThompson has said though, this is not a code writing service, you should at least make some attempt to write an example yourself.

Comment: Thank-you @explv for the somewhat helpful reply. I am surprised this simple question, which i prefaced may irritate some, received so many down votes.It seems like real coders would want to help other coders trying to learn something instead of being snobby. My problem is I do not know how to pass a graphics object, a component object, a container object, or a rectangle object so I am confused where to begin, hence writing a question on stackoverflow dot com.

Comment: I agree with @user3870315 that the documentation is not clear, (especially regarding `p`, the "intermediate container") which is why I'm here reading this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find some usages of most public api methods from grepcode. and [here](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24root@jdk%24openjdk@6-b27@javax%24swing@SwingUtilities@paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%2Cjava.awt.Component%2Cjava.awt.Container%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29&k=u) is yours.

**EDIT**

a running example may be like this

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
                JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>SwingUtilities.paintComponent method usage example");
                {
                    label.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
                }
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    // render label which is not part of component hierarchy
                    // and paint it on this panel at location (10,10) with dimension (200,50)
                    SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, label, this,  10, 10, 200, 50);
                }
            };
            frame.setContentPane(panel);
            frame.setSize(300, 200);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something in the context of a small program, 50 lines or less, that runs. I can find numerous examples myself of the method signature.

Comment: What I posted is not the method signature. It is real usages of SwingUtilities.paintComponent method.

Comment: I edited my answer providing a real running example of usage of SwingUtilities.paintComponent. hope it helps

Comment: Awesome, yes now your answer is more than a link to a method signature. Thank-you for the help with understanding this @guleryuz I think someone in the Java community will also appreciate this helpful example in the near future. :)

Comment: the link is not to a method signature, the link is to real usages of SwingUtilities.paintComponent method in some api's.

Comment: I guess the hyperlink is more than a method signature but just a little more. It is hard to understand the context of the method and how to pass in the method arguments successfully.

Comment: I think you are missing the end `html` tag in your constructor to JLabel.